# How to instantiate a new object from an abstract class containing an instance of a HashMap?

Tags: java, polymorphism, instantiation, abstract

I believe that abstract classes cannot be instantiated. However, I have a HashMap instance inside my abstract class that I want to retrieve objects from. Is there any way possible to do this? Any insight would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Edit:

I am actually looking for a way to instantiate an abstract class using a token such as

```
barnStack.push(new Animal("Cow"));
```

Comment: Instances can't be inside classes.

Comment: "_I believe that abstract classes cannot be instantiated._" In java that is not a belief, it is a fact.

Comment: I am actually looking for a way to instantiate an abstract class using a token such as barnStack.push(new Animal("Cow"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to a structure like:

```
abstract class MyClass {
    private Map<String, String> textMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void addText(String key, String value) {
        textMap.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

And you are asking how `textMap` can be used if the class cannot be instantiated. If that's correct then the answer is that it can be used by methods inside the abstract class (or subclasses if it's `protected`). Any instance of a subclass of `MyClass` can call that method which will access the `Map`.

```
class MySubclass extends MyClass {
}

MySubclass myobj = new MySubclass();
myobj.addText("Hello", "World!");
```

It is also possible to make the subclass anonymous:

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass() {};
myobj.addText("Hello", "World!");
```

However in this case it is more likely that the superclass isn't really abstract.

Comment: I am actually looking for a way to instantiate an abstract class using a token such as barnStack.push(new Animal("Cow"));

Comment: @apebeast Ok then probably the best option is an anonymous class. I'll add that to my code.

Comment: Wow, I definitely need to study more. Thank you Sprinter!

Answer (score 1):

**Abstract classes can not be instantiated in java**. [java oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

So what you have to do is create a new concrete class that extends the abstract class. Then you can instantiate the concrete subclass.

```
class ConcreteClassName extends AbstractClassName{
     //implement all the methods of the abstract class

     //optionaly you can add new methods if you want to
}
```

//  to get instance of the abstract class

```
AbstractClassName newObject = new ConcreteClassName();
```

now you have instance of your abstract class.